# Keep same session before and after registration with FOSUserBundle and Symfony2.1

Tags: session, symfony, registration, fosuserbundle

I'm working on a shopping cart and facing an issue with FOSuserBundle registration flow :

My users can add whatever they want to their cart, being or not logged/registered, but before checking out, i want them to login/register.

The main important thing is that I want after login/registration they can get back the same shopping cart they had before. To achieve it, i'm saving into the user session a random key and i'm saving this random key in the database with all articles data.

I hava no problem with the login flow, the session is kept without any change (symfony preserves all session data), so the user retrieves his session, but my problem is with registration.

When the user wants to checkout and have not an account yet, he needs to register, and when the registration is complete (with FosuserBundle, sending an activation link by mail) the user session is completely resetted so the shopping cart is lost but has not really disappeared :  Actually, a weird thing i observed is that the browser seems to deal with 2 different sessions at the same time but in 2 separate tabs, in the old browser tab (before registration), data is still here, but in the new tab the session is cleared

So my question is, is there a way to give back a user his session after a successful registration in Symfony2.1 and while using FosUserBundle?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

My security config file was the cause

I had to set the option **session_fixation_strategy** to "migrate", that now works perfectly, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Login/Logout is handled by symfony's 2 security component while registration is handled by FosUserBundle.

You can try to override the registration handler https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_controllers.md and migrate your old session: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html#session-api

Comment: Thank you artworkad but i'm already overriding FOSUserBundle registration controller for other reasons and there'n no way inside this controller to deal with the session migration/regeneration, it doesn't seem that's the place to handle it